# IIS7 integrated pipeline forms authentication caches user credentials

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have a problem regardin IIS7 integrated pipeline and forms authentication. My web application is a mix of aspx and html pages and I need to protected both of them with forms authentication.
I've managed to protect static content by removing  preconditions on FormsAuthentication modules and everything works as expcted, but when I sign out, .AUXSPATH cookie is deleted but I am still able to load static html content after that, not being redirected to login.aspx and I am beign redirected if I try to serve aspx content...

Even if I close browser and try to load same html pages the page is served normally because user credentials are somehow cached.

I am being redirected to login form only if I clear browser's cache or if I put 
`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">` in head section of html file

I've also configured output caching and have prevented all cahing for html content and after that it works fine, but I want to use caching and still being able to prevent access after signing out

What do I have to do to prevent serving html content after deleting authentication cookie regardless of html content being cached by default?!?